# How to create a Shipping Order with AdventureWorks2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, adventureworks

I'm deploying a Adventure Cycle page where the people can order one of bikes. I want to create a `Shipping Information` include (Address 1, Address 2, City, Country, Zip/Postal, and State/Province). When click the `Submit Order` it will redirect to `Complete` page to inform `User` that order is successful.

`Address` model:

```
public partial class Address
    {
        public Address()
        {
            this.SalesOrderHeaders = new HashSet<SalesOrderHeader>();
            this.SalesOrderHeaders1 = new HashSet<SalesOrderHeader>();
        }
    
        public int AddressID { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> StateProvinceID { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public System.Guid rowguid { get; set; }

        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    
        public virtual StateProvince StateProvince { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SalesOrderHeader> SalesOrderHeaders { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SalesOrderHeader> SalesOrderHeaders1 { get; set; }
    }
```

`Sales Order Header`:

```
public partial class SalesOrderHeader
    {
        public SalesOrderHeader()
        {
            this.SalesOrderDetails = new HashSet<SalesOrderDetail>();
        }
    
        public int SalesOrderID { get; set; }

        public byte RevisionNumber { get; set; }

        
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> OrderDate { get; set; }
        
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DueDate { get; set; }

        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ShipDate { get; set; }
        public byte Status { get; set; }

        public bool OnlineOrderFlag { get; set; }
        public string SalesOrderNumber { get; set; }
        public string PurchaseOrderNumber { get; set; }
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SalesPersonID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> TerritoryID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> BillToAddressID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ShipToAddressID { get; set; }
        public int ShipMethodID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CreditCardID { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will help you, 
On your Complete View you must put the model Address to the redirect method of the Complet e form:
Like

```
`Public ActionResult SubmitOrder(Address address)
   { 
       ...
       return View("Complete", address);
   }
 ` 
and 
on your Complete View
first line must be
`
@Model namespace.Model.Address

//then you can use
  @model.AddressLine1 
  @model.AddressLine2
  @model.City
  @model.PostalCode 
  @model.StateProvinceID // You will retrieve an Id here I guess but at least you will 
                         //have your data. embedded in your razor code
```

`

Comment: Actually I want to create a `Shipping Order` page for User fill the information on it. Anyway thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Create two actions in your controller eg: `ShippingOrder` one with `[HttpGet]` and the other with `[HttpPOST]` attibute. in the second actions put your model as parameter `ShippingOrder(ShippingAddress shippingAddress)`. You have many options either create a new model ShippingAddress either use Address model with the field required.